# ADODB.ConnectionClass.Open(String ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options), Windows Server 2012 R2, GAC

Tags: c#, .net, adodb, gac, windows-server-2012-r2

I need help with an error.

I imported a Database of Microsoft Access to Sql server and use `AccesDataBaseEngine`. My project works fine in  others servers, but I have an unusual case with Windows Server 2012 R2 with the next error:

```
ADODB.ConnectionClass.Open(String ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options).
```

I think that the error is probably that this version of Windows Server 2012 R2 doesn't have files Windows -> Assembly ->Gac, compared with the other version of Windows Server 2012 r2 that yeah have Gac file in Assembly, in this file Gac when it is installed AccessDataBase create the DLL Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao-version-12.0.0.

I tried copy the references and DLL in my proyect, but i cant find solution.

How can resolve this error?

[image: Error ADODB.ConnectionClass.Open(String ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options)]

Comment: Would you please edit to paste the text from your screenshot so that others can read it and copy it more easily? Also, image links rot so they do not help future readers.

Comment: I found the error: Missing a Tag <identity impersonate="false" /> in the WebConfig

Comment: That's great! You should post that as an answer and accept it  Thanks so much for coming back to let others know even though we didn't help.